# Does the tag "inside-man-series" follow our conventions?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed the tag [inside-man-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inside-man-series). Does this follow our naming conventions? Shouldn't it use the year instead of the word "series"?

Comment: It depends if it's actually a series. In that case it should have neither, rather than the appendage "-tv", which would be our naming convention. If it's a film, though, then the year would be appropriate.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Its's a series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_Man_(2022_TV_series) -- see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_Man_(disambiguation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the tag to [inside-man-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inside-man-tv), as per the standards.